# Bot Framework v4.4.3 Update Skill Manifest Template

Tags: c#, botframework

The document [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/tutorials/csharp/skill.md#update-your-skill-manifest) says update skill manifest but does not specify how to add a new skill in the manifest file.

I have the following in the main dialog:

```cs
case MasterCollectionsLuis.Intent.PlayVideo:
                        {
                            turnResult = await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(Water.PlayVideo.PlayVideoDialog));
                            break;
                        }
```

And have a base for PlayVideo and the Dialog itself as shown by the example SampleDialog and SampleDialogBase.

When I load the manifest file at http://localhost:1205/api/skill/manifest:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MasterCollections.Dialogs.Water.PlayVideo.PlayVideoDialog' while attempting to activate 'MasterCollections.Dialogs.MainDialog'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, bool throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
```

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dependency Injection error**

That error is to do with the dependency injection pipeline, without setting your `Startup.cs` file my best guess is that you haven't wired up `PlayVideoDialog` in there.

In your `Startup.cs` file you will have a section where you register your Dialogs against the dependency injection service provider like so:

```
services.AddTransient<CancelDialog>();
services.AddTransient<EscalateDialog>();
services.AddTransient<MainDialog>();
```

You simply need to add another line each time you add a new Dialog:

```
services.AddTransient<MyNewDialog>();
```

In your case you would have `PlayVideoDialog` in place of `MyNewDialog`.

Also make sure that you are **not** passing a `PlayVideoDialog` parameter into the constructor of `MainDialog` as this is not how Dialogs work, you should instead call the `AddDialog(new PlayVideoDialog(...))` method inside the constructor of `MainDialog`.

**Skills manifest question**

I haven't created a skill myself but there is additional documentation which may or may not be helpful about [adding skill support](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/howto/skills/csharp/addskillsupportforv4bot.md), [adding skills](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/howto/skills/addingskills.md), and the [skills manifest](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/reference/skills/skillmanifest.md) file itself.

In the documentation that you linked it states:

> this has been pre-populated with the Skill ID and name and a sample action which you can modify at this stage if required

which leads me to believe you can manually modify this file to fit your requirements, but you don't have to modify it if there are no changes required.